# Firebase Firestore - get error response with offline persistence

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was wondering if there was a way to get an error response from a firestore write while using offline persistence the same as if it were online. Basically, if I submit a write and the doc name has a special character that is not allowed, when online, this will throw an error. However, when offline, you don't know if there is an error until you go back online and firebase attempts to write the data to the online database.

Is there a way to get Firestore to throw an error even if using offline persistence (so that the user can be alerted that they need to change the name etc.)?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

There is no configuration option or API to control this behavior. But if you find that the SDK doesn't perform validations on document IDs that it could reasonably perform, I recommend [filing an issue on the SDK repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues) to get that check added.